# How to access the value of a java script variable inside a haml file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a function in my java script file which returns a value of a text area form before and end user submits the form. As I am not using java script inside my haml file, I am just wondering to know how I can access this returned value from my function in javascript, into my haml file:

```
this.findControlTextAreaValue = function(target) {


if (target === undefined) {
    target = $('body');
  }
  var form = $(target).find('form.ordered_control');

  $("form.ordered_control").find("input[type!=submit], select, textarea").on("change", function(event) {
    var current_target = $(event.currentTarget);
    var my_form = current_target.parents('form');

    var value_exists = my_form.find(".existing_control_id").val();
    return value_exists;
  });
}
```

I need a variable in my haml file, which should receive this returned value and perform some checks on it before submitting the form!

Thanks for you help

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with that return value?

Comment: The return value is an id. I need to check if that id already existed in my database and based on that greyout a button.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do these checks also in a script tag and submit the form using .submit() instead of using ruby.

```
:javascript
  place your javascript code here
```